# Django-cms no reverse match using apphook from admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-cms

i hope you can help me.

I'm using django 1.11 and django-cms.

I created an apphook to manage urls from a certain page.

I already created the page (with all translations) and associated it with my application so everything works fine.

My problem occurs when, from admin, i'm inside the change page related to an instance of a model. I see the button 'view on site' that uses an url created this way:

> /admin/r/content_type_id/object_id/
>
> django.contrib.contenttypes.views.shortcut  admin:view_on_site

Clicking on it i get the error

> Reverse for 'myapp_mymodel_detail' not found

Do you know the correct way to make it works?